# Is "be my guests" correctly used in the following case?

Tags: phrases, idioms

> **Speaker A:** We want to ask you some questions. If you don't mind, of
>   course.
>
> **Speaker B:** [He opens the door of his house] Sure, **be my guests**.

Is the idiom being used correctly? If not, what would be a better alternative?

Comment: Upvoted answer, but want to add that "be my guests" would sound strange, even though grammatically correct.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/guest  Scroll down to *be my guest*

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45335/what-is-the-origin-of-be-my-guest-idiom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Be my guest" is an idiom that's usually used to (politely) give permission for someone to do something.

> If you want to edit my manuscript, be my guest.
>
> Can I try out your new TARDIS? Be my guest.

It indicates the other person should feel free to act as he/she pleases.

In your question it appears the idiom is being used both figuratively and literally, `B` is inviting `A` into his house (as guests) and giving `B` permission to ask questions.

The only questionable bit is the use of **guests** instead of **guest**. As far as I know, "*be my guest*" is the conventional idiom, though given `B` is referring to a group of people, the the plural form is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: In a real-life example, would someone use *be my guest* even if the person is talking with a group of people?

Comment: Conversations usually occur between two people, but may have many observers/listeners. I'd say it's perfectly acceptable to say either *be my guest*, (since you're technically only talking to one person) or *be my guests* (if the permission given is extended to all listeners)

Comment: Nice answer. Welcome to the site!

Comment: 'Be my guests' in this situation would be an obvious variation of the usual idiom here, and a reasonable expression to use. Idioms differ in their degree of fixedness; _John and Sue are keeping their heads down_ is far more colloquial than _John and Sue need to get grips on their children_.

Comment: "*Be my guest* is an idiom that's usually used to (politely) give permission for someone to do something." -- source?

Comment: *[something you say when you give someone permission to do or use something](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/be-my-guest)*

Comment: It is debatable whether the phrase is '**usually** used to (**politely**) give permission' (and nothing else).

Answer (score -1):

As in my place in Kuala Lumpur, we understand it this way: Be My Guest related to something that we try to challenge someone to do it with circumstances and difficulty until it's merely seems like will never done or succeed at all. eg: I'm the one who recovered from nightmares, you wanna get into my life? Be My Guest...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If I understand you correctly, "Be my guest" is sometimes used in this context with something nobody wants to do, e.g. among people living together A: "Someone needs to clean the kitchen." B: "Be my guest." Here, B is not expecting anything to get done and is not offering to clean. But sometimes it is used in a more genuine way to actually invite people to do something they want to do.